# Append buttons to a list by using hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a ul list of elements

```
<ul id="list">
 </ul>
```

and two text fields and submit button in the html

```
Name: <input type="text" id='name'/><br/>
Surname: <input type="text" id='surname'/><br/>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

By clicking on the submit button I am appending elements from this field to a list

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
                    if($('#name').val()!="" && $('#surname').val()!="") {
                    $('#list').append("<li>" + "Name: " + $('#name').val() + " <br/>Surname: " + $('#surname').val() + "</li>");

                    $('#name').val("");
                    $('#surname').val("");

                }
            });
```

**THIS IS THE PROBLEM:**
I want by using hover to append two buttons on a particular li from this list, when I am on that li elements buttons to show, and when i am off buttons to hide. Here is my code:

```
 $("ul").find("li").hover(
          function() {
          $('li').append('<button id="but1">Button1</button>' 
          + '<button id="but2">Button1</button>');}, 
           function(){
                $('#but1').remove();
                $('#but2').remove();
      });
```

And this is another try but it appends the buttons at the and of the list not in a particular li from ul list

```
$('#list').each(function(){
                    console.log($(this));
                        $(this).hover(
                          function() {
                            $(this).append('<button id="but1">Button1</button>' + '<button id="but2">Button1</button>');
                          }, 
                          function(){
                            $('#but1').remove();
                             $('#but2').remove();
                          }

                          );


                    });
```

Comment: Please indent and format your code correctly then check for proper nesting... You may be missing a paren?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use 2 methods - css and jQuery

**Method 1** -
In css method you can simply hide-show buttons on `:hover` as follow

```
#list li button{display:none;}
#list li:hover button{display:block;}
```

jsfiddle demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/ypnajsuc/1/

**Method 2** -
In jQuery method as `li` content is dynamic you should use `on` - `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$('#list').on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
        $(this).append('<button>Button1</button>' 
                    + '<button>Button2</button>');
});
$('#list').on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
        $(this).find('button').remove();
});
```

jsfiddle demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/ypnajsuc/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```js
$("#list li").hover(function() {
  $(this).append('<button id="but1" >button1</button><button id="but2">button2</button>');
}, function() {
  $(this).empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: this is the solution I am looking for but still doesn't work, I think that that happens because I am appending the elements in ul list by using jQuery, they are not in the html.

Comment: If you create a jsfiddle for that , can look for problem you are actually facing

Comment: So you want to first add three `li` elements and then buttons on hovered `li`

Comment: when I hover  li element buttons show for that element

Comment: It doesn't matter the number of li elements

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
$("#list li").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).append('<button id="but1">Button1</button>' +
            '<button id="but2">Button1</button>');
    },
    function() {
        $('#but1').remove();
        $('#but2').remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your selector, right now you're selecting the entire list, you need to specify the items.

```
$('#list li').each(function() { ... });
```

Comment: This is not the case at all.

Comment: It is, actually.  This works perfectly, but other people have pointed out that .hover() can be used on multiple elements, so you don't need the .each(), but the heart of the matter is that his selector was selecting the overall list rather than the list elements, like I said.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#list li").hover(function() {
  $(this).html('<button>button1</button><button>button2</button>'); }, function() { $(this).empty(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
       <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>

  </ul>
```